# Problem Scaping Instagram Hashtag posts count with hashtags that have special characters

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So i can scrape instagram hashtag posts count with the code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

ig_link = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/100x35/'

driver.get(ig_link)

# Scrape Posts Count
posts_count = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span').text

print(posts_count)
driver.close()
```

The problem I have is when a hash tag has a flag in it for example:

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/100x35/

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

ig_link = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/100x35/'

driver.get(ig_link)

# Scrape Posts Count
posts_count = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span').text

print(posts_count)
driver.close()
```

I get the following error:

*Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span"}*

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to do encode the URL to get the UTF-8 code for the flag.
In this case, you can replace the

> 

with

> %F0%9F%87%B5%F0%9F%87%B7

to get a text-only URL and yield the same results. This tool should be useful if you are going about this manually: [link](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

urllib also has a tool if you want to do it automatically in python

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> query = 'Hellö Wörld@Python'
>>> urllib.parse.quote(query)
'Hell%C3%B6%20W%C3%B6rld%40Python'
```

More on that [here](https://www.urlencoder.io/python/)

Comment: I replaced the url with:

Comment: I replaced the url with:

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/100x35%F0%9F%87%B5%F0%9F%87%B7/

Still didnt work.  Whats weird is that either method brings me to the page with no problem.  Either with the flag icon or the text-only url.  When I inspect the page with the text-only url and search for the xpath below:

//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span

I a match.  But selenium says:

*no such element:*